# Unexpected token in export default class extends React.Component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I get a build error for a curly brace.

```
const {pages, contentOffset, contentFactor}  = useWindowWidth(); 
      ^
```

Is there a certain way I need to write the `const` variables? Do I need to put them in a different area? If I put the `const` variables in the `render()` function I get another error stating:

`React Hook "useEffect" is called conditionally. React Hooks must be called in the exact same order in every component render  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks`

````
/** @jsx jsx */
import { jsx } from "theme-ui"
import styled from '@emotion/styled'
import addToMailchimp from 'gatsby-plugin-mailchimp'
import { Parallax } from "react-spring/renderprops-addons.cjs"
import Divider from "@lekoarts/gatsby-theme-cara/src/elements/divider"
import Inner from "@lekoarts/gatsby-theme-cara/src/elements/inner"
import Content from "@lekoarts/gatsby-theme-cara/src/elements/content"
import SVG from "@lekoarts/gatsby-theme-cara/src/components/svg"
import { UpDown, UpDownWide } from "@lekoarts/gatsby-theme-cara/src/styles/animations"
import Layout from "@lekoarts/gatsby-theme-cara/src/components/layout"
import React, { useState, useEffect }  from "react"
import { window, exists } from "browser-monads"

const Input = styled.input` 
  background: #242b3c;
    border: 0px;
    font-size: 1em;
    padding:10px;
    margin:5px;
    color:white;
`

const SubmitButton = styled.input`
  border: 0px;
    padding: 10px;
    background: #3caf7b;
    color: white;
    font-size: 1em;
    font-weight: 800;
`   




const Classroom = () => {


 const {pages, contentOffset, contentFactor}  = useWindowWidth(); 
 

        return (
       <Layout>

    <Parallax pages={pages} >

    
      <Divider  speed={-0.2}
      offset={0.1}
      factor={1}  bg="linear-gradient(to right, Maroon 0%, Tomato 100%)"
      sx={{ clipPath: `polygon(0 15%, 100% 25%, 100% 85%, 0 75%)` }}/>

      <Divider speed={0.2} offset={0.6} factor={1}>
      <UpDown>
        <SVG icon="triangle" hiddenMobile width={48} stroke color="icon_orange" left="10%" top="20%" />
        <SVG icon="hexa" width={48} stroke color="icon_red" left="60%" top="70%" />
        <SVG icon="box" width={6} color="icon_darker" left="60%" top="15%" />
      </UpDown>
      <UpDownWide>
        <SVG icon="arrowUp" hiddenMobile width={16} color="icon_blue" left="80%" top="10%" />
        <SVG icon="triangle" width={12} stroke color="icon_brightest" left="90%" top="50%" />
        <SVG icon="circle" width={16} color="icon_darker" left="70%" top="90%" />
        <SVG icon="triangle" width={16} stroke color="icon_darkest" left="30%" top="65%" />
        <SVG icon="cross" width={16} stroke color="icon_pink" left="28%" top="15%" />
        <SVG icon="circle" width={6} color="icon_darkest" left="75%" top="10%" />
        <SVG icon="upDown" hiddenMobile width={8} color="icon_darkest" left="45%" top="10%" />
      </UpDownWide>
      <SVG icon="circle" hiddenMobile width={24} color="icon_darker" left="5%" top="70%" />
      <SVG icon="circle" width={6} color="icon_darkest" left="4%" top="20%" />
      <SVG icon="circle" width={12} color="icon_darkest" left="50%" top="60%" />
      <SVG icon="upDown" width={8} color="icon_darkest" left="95%" top="90%" />
      <SVG icon="upDown" hiddenMobile width={24} color="icon_darker" left="40%" top="80%" />
      <SVG icon="triangle" width={8} stroke color="icon_darker" left="25%" top="5%" />
      <SVG icon="circle" width={64} color="icon_green" left="95%" top="5%" />
      <SVG icon="box" hiddenMobile width={64} color="icon_purple" left="5%" top="90%" />
      <SVG icon="box" width={6} color="icon_darkest" left="10%" top="10%" />
      <SVG icon="box" width={12} color="icon_darkest" left="40%" top="30%" />
      <SVG icon="hexa" width={16} stroke color="icon_darker" left="10%" top="50%" />
      <SVG icon="hexa" width={8} stroke color="icon_darker" left="80%" top="70%" />
    </Divider>

    <Content  offset={contentOffset} factor={contentFactor}>


    
   <div style={{ color: `white`}}>
        <Inner >
        <h1  sx={{
          color: "heading",
          m: 1,
        }}>hi </h1>

        <h2>Solution</h2>
        </Inner>
       
        <div>
           
      </div>

      <div>
        <h2>Useful to</h2>
        <p>
      Parents, teachers, students, school districts, home Schools
        </p>

      </div>

       <div id="ttm-form">
                <h2>Get Connected</h2>
                
            
       </div>




    </div>
    </Content>
    </Parallax>
    </Layout>
        )    
  

}

function useWindowWidth() {
  const [width, setWidth] = useState(window.innerWidth);
  // default mobile
  let breakpoints = {
    pages: 1.8, 
    contentOffset: 0.4, 
    contentFactor: 0.8, 
    width: width
  };

  if(exists(window)){
    useEffect(() => {

      const handleResize = () => setWidth(window.innerWidth);
      window.addEventListener('resize', handleResize);
  
      return () => {
        window.removeEventListener('resize', handleResize);
      };
    });
  
    switch (true) {
      case (width >= 768):
        breakpoints.pages = 1.5;
  
        breakpoints.contentOffset = 0.1; 
        breakpoints.contentFactor = 0.8; 
        break;
    }
  }
  
 

  return breakpoints;
}

export default Classroom



}```
````

Comment: You can’t use hooks inside class components. If you remove useWindowWidth() does the error go away? Either change the component to a functional component or move the hook logic to the class component hooks.

Comment: The error does not go away if I remove useWindowWidth. If I change it to a functional component it breaks the app too.

Comment: So aside from that what does the error say? It says that useEffect is being used conditionally. If you move the if statement inside useEffect, does the error go away? Also class components should be capitalized.

Comment: I moved the if statement even though it's needed but I get the "Invalid hook call". Darn, someway I need to make this hook work with a class component it seems.

Comment: I made it into a functional component and I get this error now: 

 React Hook "useWindowWidth" is called in function "classroom" which is neither a React function component or a custom React Hook function  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks
  152:5   error    React Hook "useEffect" is called conditionally. React Hooks must be called in the exact same order in every component render               react-hooks/rules-of-hooks

Comment: Change it to Classroom with a capital “C”

Comment: It says now React Hook "useEffect" is called conditionally. I have similar code somewhere else and I don't get these errors. Very strange

Comment: I'd recommend to update your question to include your most up to date code, but just to confirm have you: 1) changed "classroom" to "Classroom" 2) Have you updated all your hooks to move useEffect outside `if` statements? 3) Have you removed usage of hooks in class (non functional) components. Those three things throughout your entire application?

Comment: I updated the code but I'm not sure about your number 2 question on how this is supposed to be.

Comment: I mean move the if statement inside the useEffect. You can conditionally execute code inside the if statement that’s inside the useEffevt

Comment: Ok it worked by converting it to a functional component but I had to build it again to make it work. Thank you

Comment: And I also had to convert the file from .js to .tsx